# Is there a way for Git LFS to pull files only from a specific branch?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have been trying to pull `lfs` files from a specific branch from a GitHub repo.

It seems that `git lfs fetch BRANCH_NAME` or `git lfs pull BRANCH_NAME` do nothing.

The only thing that worked in my case is doing `git lfs fetch --all`. But it is not convenient for me to fetch the binaries from all the banches and their history as this amounts to more than 50 GBs.

Comment: Files are stored in *commits*, not in branch names. Branch names select some particular commit, but two or more branch names may select the *same* commit, and branch names can and do change which commit they select. (Meanwhile, less important but you should know it: `git pull` does not pull files: it fetches and then merges *commits*.) Given the way LFS stores pointer files in Git and the file data itself elsewhere, LFS will have limitations that probably make it impossible to do what you want, but it's not really clear to me what *result* you want.

Answer (score 0):

The git-lfs man page https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-fetch.adoc states the following command can be used to fetch all lfs files of the given branches with

> • Fetch all the LFS objects from the default remote that are referenced
> by any commit in the main and develop branches

```
git lfs fetch --all origin main develop
```

I had to adapt the command to the following to get it to work

```
git lfs fetch -all origin origin/main
```